# angularjs share variable between functions

Tags: angularjs, scope

Within a controller, I'd like to share data between two functions.  For example:

```
controllers.controller('rightDrawerCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.shared_id;

  $scope.getId = function ()  {
  // get the id via $http, using a secondary id to retrieve the shared_id
  }

  $scope.useId = function () {
  // use the shared_id to make a different api call
  }

});
```

In this example however, when useId() is called, shared_id is undefined.

I presume this is because useId was 'created' while shared_id was undefined, so hasn't been notified of the new value.

The only way I've found to fix this is by using two controllers: [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Is there a better way to do this, using only 1 controller?

Comment: if you must used this method, add a timeout around shared_id to init it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I simply had to wrap the variable assignment in $scope.$apply

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.shared_id = 1234;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.shared_id;
```

After the above statement the `shared_id` variable of `$scope` should be undefined - because you haven't assigned it any value.

Despite this the variable is still accessible inside any scope functions because `$scope` is global for them. And don't forget that you should access it like `$scope.shared_id` in all the places.

However if you initialize it in the following manner:

```
$scope.shared_id = 'no id';
```

.. it would not return undefined.

You can initialize this variable via `ng-init` too.

Comment: While that would stop it from returning 'undefined' - I cannot access any changes that have been made to the variable since init

Answer (score 0):

Call userId() function when getId() function get result from $http request.

Comment: Unfortunately getId must be called independently of useId.  I've adjusted the example to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this with `this` is much easier.

```
var self = this;
this.shared_id;


  $scope.getId = function ()  {
    console.log(self.shared_id) ;
  }

  $scope.useId = function () {
    console.log(self.shared_id) ;
  }
```